# Something not right about my JavaScript procedure

Tags: javascript, html

As part of a spellcheck algorithm I'm creating, I have written a function that returns an array of all of words that have 1 letter replaced from a given word. The letter replacements must be distance 1 away on the keyboard; hence I made the following map

```
     var kdmap = {'a': ['q','w','s','z'],
                 'b': ['v','g','h','n'],
                 'c': ['x','d','f','v'],
                 'd': ['s','e','r','f','c','x'],
                 'e': ['w','s','d','r'],
                 'f': ['d','r','t','g','v','c'],
                 'g': ['f','t','y','h','b','v'],
                 'h': ['g','y','u','j','n','b'],
                 'i': ['u','h','j','i'],
                 'j': ['h','n','m','k','i','u','y'],
                 'k': ['j','i','o','l','m'],
                 'l': ['k','o','p'],
                 'm': ['n','j','k'],
                 'n': ['b','h','j','m'],
                 'o': ['i','k','l','p'],
                 'p': ['o','l'],
                 'q': ['a','w'],
                 'r': ['e','d','f','t'],
                 's': ['a','w','e','d','x','z'],
                 't': ['r','f','g','y'],
                 'u': ['y','h','j','i'],
                 'v': ['c','f','g','b'],
                 'w': ['q','a','s','e'],
                 'x': ['z','s','d','c'],
                 'y': ['t','g','h','u'],
                 'z': ['a','s','x']
                };
```

that is used in the following function.

```
    function letter_replacements(w)
    {
        /* Given a word w, return an array of all strings that are w
           with 1 letter replaced, that letter being one which is distance
           1 away on the keyboard
        */
        var A = new Array();
        for (var i = 0, j = w.length; i < j; ++i)
        {
            var thisChar = w[i];
            var closeChars = kdmap[thischar];
            for (var k = 0, n = closeChars.length; k < n; ++k)
                A.push(w.slice(0,i)+closeChars[k]+w.slice(i+1,j))
        }
        return A;
    }
```

When I run the page containing that code, there are no errors on my browsers JavaScript console. However, when I create a fiddle to test the function, I'm not getting any output.

Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5hQyp/

Any idea what I've done wrong?

Comment: I have been seeing a lot of `new Array()` instead of `[]` lately.

Comment: `thischar` is undefined.

Comment: variable names are case sensitive. `thisChar` != `thischar`

Comment: `closeChars` will be undefined for non-letter chars. For example " " cause an error.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko: That's okay, because a "word", as defined in my program, consists only of sequences of letter characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated your fiddle with some fixes. I will detail the issues below:

1. thisChar and thischar are not the same thing. Case sensitive.
2. You are not guaranteed to end up with an array for closeChars, so:

   var closeChars = kdmap[thisChar] || [];
3. Your map only covers lowercase characters so:

   var thisChar = w[i].toLowerCase();

Below is the actual code after modification.

```
var kdmap = {'a': ['q','w','s','z'],
 'b': ['v','g','h','n'],
 'c': ['x','d','f','v'],
 'd': ['s','e','r','f','c','x'],
 'e': ['w','s','d','r'],
 'f': ['d','r','t','g','v','c'],
 'g': ['f','t','y','h','b','v'],
 'h': ['g','y','u','j','n','b'],
 'i': ['u','h','j','i'],
 'j': ['h','n','m','k','i','u','y'],
 'k': ['j','i','o','l','m'],
 'l': ['k','o','p'],
 'm': ['n','j','k'],
 'n': ['b','h','j','m'],
 'o': ['i','k','l','p'],
 'p': ['o','l'],
 'q': ['a','w'],
 'r': ['e','d','f','t'],
 's': ['a','w','e','d','x','z'],
 't': ['r','f','g','y'],
 'u': ['y','h','j','i'],
 'v': ['c','f','g','b'],
 'w': ['q','a','s','e'],
 'x': ['z','s','d','c'],
 'y': ['t','g','h','u'],
 'z': ['a','s','x']
};

function letter_replacements(w) {
  /* Given a word w, return an array of all strings that are w
   with 1 letter replaced, that letter being one which is distance
   1 away on the keyboard
  */
  var A = new Array();
  for (var i = 0, j = w.length; i < j; ++i)
  {
    var thisChar = w[i].toLowerCase();
    var closeChars = kdmap[thisChar] || [];
    for (var k = 0, n = closeChars.length; k < n; ++k)
      A.push(w.slice(0,i)+closeChars[k]+w.slice(i+1,j))
  }
  return A;
}

var myWord = "Obama smokes cigarettes.";
var myArray = letter_replacements(myWord);
document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = "<p>" + myArray.join('') + "</p>";
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5hQyp/1/

Answer (score 2):

To me it looks like you have problems with these two lines of code right here:

```
 var thisChar = w[i];
 var closeChars = kdmap[thischar];
```

Must be:

```
 var thisChar = w[i];
 var closeChars = kdmap[thisChar.toLowerCase()];
 if (closeChars === undefined)
    continue;
```

1) Your casing is off. **thisChar** not **thischar**.

2) You don't account for space characters. So closeChars can be undefined.

3) You have to call toLowerCase on every character that you get, because there are no capital case chars in your JavaScript object.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ph9DN/)**

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to write a program to check case ;)

Look at the console and you see the error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: thischar is not defined`

Looking at the code you messed up casing.

```
var thisChar = w[i];
       ^^^
var closeChars = kdmap[thischar];
                           ^^^
```